# Sublime Text: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gopls'

Tags: linux, go, autocomplete, sublimetext3, language-server-protocol

Installed LSP server on Sublime Text 3, then enabled gopls from the `LSP: Enable Language Server Globally` > selected `gopls`.

Also executed below command on terminal.

```
GO111MODULE=on go get golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest
```

Error shown:

[image: Could not start gopls]

LSP.sublime-settings

```
{
    "clients":
    {
        "gopls":
        {
            "enabled": true
        }
    }
}
```

gopls command

```
❯  which gopls
/home/user/go/bin/gopls
```

I am using MX Linux. Please help !

[Source](https://github.com/golang/tools/tree/master/gopls)

Comment: is `gopls` available on the `PATH`?

Comment: `gopls version` works on the terminal.

Comment: Have you restarted Sublime since installing `gopls`?

Comment: @MattDMo Yes, several times. Even restarted PC several times.

Comment: Try to define it clearly(full path). See https://github.com/sublimelsp/LSP/blob/3245597e023e6c10d28d990bdb368e9265682250/LSP.sublime-settings#L250 or similar settings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This solved the problem.

```
## LSP.sublime-settings -- User
{
    "clients":
    {
        "gopls":
        {
            "command": [
                "/home/rahulbali/go/bin/gopls",
                "-v",
                "-rpc.trace",
                "-logfile=/home/rahulbali/gopls.log"
            ],
            "enabled": true,
            "env": {
                "PATH": "home/rahulbali/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin"
            },
            "scopes":["source.go"],
            "syntaxes": [
                "Packages/Go/Go.sublime-syntax",
                "Packages/GoSublime/syntax/GoSublime-Go-Recommended.sublime-syntax",
            ],
            "settings": {
                "gopls.usePlaceholders": true,
                "gopls.completeUnimported": true,
            },
            "languageId": "go"

        }
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/43746#issuecomment-761760279

Edit: Make 'gopls' is in your shell path.

Comment: If you are doing a Fresh Install of GoLang and Sublime Text, this link should solve with ease. https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/subl.md#sublime-text

Answer (score 1):

What sublime text quotes is:

```json
{
    "clients": {
        "gopls": {
            "enabled": true,
            "command": ["gopls"],
            "selector": "source.go",
            "initializationOptions": {
                "experimentalWorkspaceModule": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Giving the absolute path (`which gopls`) to gopls binary should solve the 'not found' problem.

```json
{
    "clients": {
        "gopls": {
            "enabled": true,
            "command": ["/Users/xxx/go/bin/gopls"],
            "selector": "source.go",
            "initializationOptions": {
                "experimentalWorkspaceModule": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```